# How to install VSCodium from downloaded .tar.gz file

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, deb, parrot-os

I am using Parrot OS. I have just downloaded VSCodium.tar.gz file.I have also unzipped it. But the preinstalled version is not yet updated. Could you please help me updating my VSCodium?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you be a little more specific with what `not yet updated` means and what you want to update to? A specific version?

Comment: VSCodium Current Version: 1.47.3
I wanna update it to version: 1.53.2
My OS is Parrot OS. I have downloaded the .tar.gz file too. But I dont know the preinstalled directory to update the previous version. Or is there any way to update my VSCodium?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Install it through snap, the [`1.54.3` version is available](https://snapcraft.io/codium):

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install codium --classic
sudo snap run codium
```

Answer (score 1):

You need update if is it in Parrot.

First Hand source
https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/268#event-7024198250
or at your risk with the standard terminal command from Download folder

```
sudo tar -xzvf VSCodium-linux-x64-XXX.tar.gz -C /usr/share/codium
```